# Why do rubys public and private keywords/methods return Object?

Tags: ruby

This snippet:

```
a = private
p a
p a.class
```

gives me:

```
Object
Class
```

I'm not sure whether `private` and `public` are keywords or methods in Ruby, however, why do they return `Object` (I mean the class) ? Is there a historical or practical reason for this odd behavior?

I've tested this with Ruby 2.1, Rubinius 2.2.6 and JRuby 1.7.12.

Comment: Checking that it behaves the same on Rubinius and JRuby is very diligent. But the fact that they behave the same as MRI suggests that the behaviour is not related to those specific implementations, but is an inherent behaviour of the Ruby programming language itself, so I removed those tags.

Comment: ok, I just wanted to make sure it isn't some odd behavior of the standard ruby interpreter ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because they are not keywords, but methods defined on Module: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-private. They return a module which received the call, if you call it in the top level of the application, this receiver is Object class.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I'm missing one little thing: WHY do they return ```self``` and not the methods they changed the visibility of?

Comment: @le_me - They can't return methods they change to private, because those methods are not defined yet when the method is executed without params. `self` is the only logical object to be returned from those methods.